# Is this expression correct?

Tags: phrase-usage, vocabulary

Is it possible to say:

> Nobody seems to know the man closer.

I am not sure about the expression **"to know someone closer"**.

Comment: Can you give us more context on the meaning? It's not idiomatic as far as I know..there may be a better way to say it.

Comment: Either you need to speak about knowing the man *better* or to continue with a phrase such as: *Nobody seems to know the man (standing) closer to the door.*

Comment: I think I need to use the word "better" because the sentence is concerning relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of "closer", use "better". While closeness can be used to describe the strength of a relationship (e.g. "Nobody seems to be closer to the man"), knowledge of someone is usually qualified with "better":

> Nobody seems to know the man better.

It might also help to introduce the word "any", if you want to convey the meaning that someone knows the man to a little extent, but not very well.

> Nobody seems to know the man *any* better.

Comment: Using "better" instead of "closer" now sounds more idiomatic to me. The text in which it appeared was from someone who maybe translated word by word from his mother tongue.